# How to resolve dependencies in Bamboo build?

Tags: java, git, scala, sbt, bamboo

I have created bamdoo build wich checkouting git repository and started sbt build with tests. There are several sbt reposotories including one from local network. So bamboo build fails with **strange message**:

```
[0m ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::[0m
[0m ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::[0m
[0m ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::[0m
[0m :: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;${version.jboss.logging}: not found[0m
```

In logs I see:

```
Resolving org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;3.1.1.GA
```

So `${version.jboss.logging}` was resolving correct.

But further logs are frustrating for me:

```
 http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/${version.jboss.logging}/jboss-logging-${version.jboss.logging}.pom
 http://myRepo/repo/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/${version.jboss.logging}/jboss-logging-${version.jboss.logging}.pom
```

Why sbt tries this URLs with `${version.jboss.logging}` instead of `3.1.1.GA`?

Is it normal for sbt to log dependecies URL without resolving versions variables or not?

How to resolve this?

**Important**

1. My Project do **not** depend on `org.jboss.logging` directly, it is a transitive dependency.
2. On my local machine **not** on bamboo server this project compiles successfully without unresolved dependencies even if I delete whole local sbt repository.
3. I have **manually** uploaded jars to the local network repository. And it did not help.

Comment: You may want to add who sets that variable, what version of sbt you are using, and the .sbt source code, if it's short enough. You can also try building (locally and on Bamboo) a new empty SBT project with one dependency added by variable, to easier test this case.

Comment: Does this also fail outside Bamboo? I guess so, but need confirmation. Can you reproduce the issue with a minimalistic `build.sbt` locally?

Comment: First it do not reproduced localy, second I am trying :)

Comment: Not sure if this works, but it worked for me when I copied the specific dependency from my maven repo .m2 to .ivy2